# How to have a switch sensitive to a specific voltage ? (NO if v < v0)

Tags: relay, potentiometer

I have a `0-10v` tension from a potentiometer generated current (1), and I would like to use something like a relay to switch on/off a `16A 230v` current (2) if (1) is below say `0.1v` or some value `Vs` that I could tune (eg., `0.01v < Vs < 1.0v`).

How can I achieve this ? I would like also to have something

- precise: the value is finely tuned and the switch is very repeatable (reliable), and
- as simple as possible eg., without voltage transformation if
  possible, keeping low cost and complications to a minimum.

Comment: Use a comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of comparators available from Digi-Key, Mouser or elsewhere. They are very common devices that symbolically can look like an operational amplifier. If precision is important, this is the way to go.

Some comparators have an open collector/drain that can drive small relays as shown on the left. Otherwise a transistor can be used to buffer a low current push-pull comparators shown on the right.

Some have hysteresis as shown in the lower diagram to prevent relay chatter.

I don't have preference. Choose based on your application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXmHId.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGTCUc.png)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Here's [a Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBDcQq7bQkCgQC+AvMijJ4ccOFiQwkQmBQ1ilYWDwDF0tthogAXgwB2DAE5N6EMNAxg6CFHjDEXuyCmbkqKedKB8HiGNmxGINYoINghkdjRCX7GZpbWbBbxiWhZgjRUvLhwbABKuapUUYL4klT5EgVQ0AhsAOa5sYZV+Y2QbTGJcQm0MgVsAO4DA5XDSVBsYBih2VSEoYTittJNwsT0JQwAzgCWhwAuHKYAxgwT4Coxzty8Tyh3a4-RrIlPfZNgPGm9xW83+Dzm3zyYzKkIqwOq4ka9QgvWaCww4lwhhQqhGflxOia0SYMDUxDwCEURHJkGIhEISBgcC2gSaXmqbLAjPkSHYADNBMIYvwYpBQiLhnYkGh+ljPqLDD1anc5UIRGLBHhEWwACYKzXiJUucRfAByCAc7EmRqFRq1oP1xv1cz+eMFAjo0TV8zKnvdtA+3qRVEUtR2Ko1ONCGoBY2tMjhNABUIdSYEieTsfmADd9Vm5XhGhBKAMENBqaw9jQEK43GGYC0tBA089aMnC5J+GtoK5sGRCEsQsRDJ5BLg2dyrW2xLwNR2+rFwNEAGIoyShlggABqAHsADYXVq3IA) that shows how you could do this:

[image: Circuit]

(you can adjust the potentiometer and the input reference voltage using the sliders on the right hand side of the simulation window)

The zener diode and 33kΩ resistor form a voltage reference. The exact voltage is set by the zener's \$V_{Z}\$, and in this simulation I went with a 3V zener diode. This voltage is then scaled using the potentiometer. A trimmer pot with a few tens of turns would give you a lot of control over the \$V_s\$ value you want to set, and you can measure it with a multimeter.

The 0-10V input voltage is compared to the reference \$V_s\$ value. The comparator will need at least a 10V supply. When \$V_1 < V_s\$, the comparator outputs its positive rail supply voltage (e.g. 10V). When \$V_1 > V_s\$, the comparator outputs its negative rail supply voltage (0V).

The output of the comparator drives the gate of a MOSFET. You'll need one that can handle the relay coil gate current, and with a \$V_{gs(max)}\$ exceeding the comparator supply voltage. So if you use 12V to power the comparator, the MOSFET you pick must have a \$V_{gs(max)}\$ of more than 12V.

The diode over the relay coil is a flyback diode. It protects the MOSFET against inductive spikes when the relay coil is switched off. A Schottky diode is a typical choice here, and you can find advice for picking appropriate flyback diodes elsewhere on this site.

You could also replace the MOSFET and relay with a solid state relay (SSR) breakout board that takes a logic level input to switch the mains load. In this case you'd add a potential divider to the output of the comparator in order to scale down the output voltage to a logic level. For example, if you're using a 12V supply you could use a 24kΩ and 9.1kΩ resistor to divide that down to 3.3V. This would then be a safe voltage level to drive the SSR breakout's input pin with.